# How can I clean up after a Singleton in C++?

Tags: design-patterns, visual-c++, memory-leaks

The following trivial demo writes "memory leak: 8" to the console, for me.
If I comment out the GetInstance() line in main(), it writes "memory leak: 0".
Even more weird, if I comment out the "void * dummy = nullptr;" line in TestSingleton, I get "memory leak: 1".

What in the world is going on?

There's only one heap allocation happening here, and it gets deleted. So how is this leaking?

```
#include <iostream>

#include <crtdbg.h>
#include <conio.h>

struct TestSingleton
{
    static TestSingleton * instance;    
    void* dummy = nullptr;

    static TestSingleton & GetInstance()
    {
        if (!instance) instance = new TestSingleton();
        return *instance;
    }

    static void Destroy()
    {
        delete instance;
        instance = nullptr;
    }
};

TestSingleton* TestSingleton::instance = nullptr;

int main()
{
    _CrtMemState state1;
    _CrtMemState state2;
    _CrtMemState state3;

    _CrtMemCheckpoint(&state1);

    {
        TestSingleton& t = TestSingleton::GetInstance();
        TestSingleton::Destroy();
    }

    _CrtMemCheckpoint(&state2);
    _CrtMemDifference(&state3, &state1, &state2);
    size_t difference = state3.lTotalCount;

    std::cout << "memory leak: " << difference << "\n";

    char dmy = getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I can explain getting `1`: a size of an  instance of an empty class (with no members) can't be 0. It's compiler-dependent, I think, and MS uses `1`. An `8` is a size of a void pointer in a 64-bit build.

Comment: But I'm deleting the instance. There shouldn't be Any instance. And the static pointer to the instance existed before the first heap check point. It should be loaded with nullptr before any code is run.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out, or at least I've uncovered a clue. When linking against the debug runtime, because of project settings related to libraries I'm linking against, I'm ending up with the CrtDbgFlag set in such a way that allocations aren't getting released. The problem goes away after building in release mode, and it goes away in debug mode if I call _CrtSetDbgFlag(0) before allocating and deallocating.

If I do either of those things, this program reports "memory leak: 0".

Comment: Oh no, but now it's doing it again in debug mode, Setting CrtDbgFlag to 0 isn't enough.